# Failed to upload sqlite database to google drive

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-android-api

I want to upload my application database to google drive.

I have tried several time but each time unfortunately it gets failure. Here is the code that brought me tons of failures.

Please show me a proper path to deal with that. Anyone's help will be highly appreciated.

```
OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
InputStream is = null;
try {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    is = new FileInputStream(dbPath);
    int c;
    while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0)
         outputStream.write(buf, 0, c);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
     try {
        outputStream.flush(); outputStream.close();
        if (is != null )is.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("Viki")
                    .setMimeType("application/x-sqlite3")
                    .setStarred(true).build();

 // create a file in root folder
 Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: be more descriptive and format added code

Comment: Actually this is my first question in stack overflow. It shows no exceptions or errors... It just not working... Not sure what to do!!!

Comment: So you want to upload an sql file to Drive, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Could you please help me out? @noogui